# Proof of a sequence $\{S_n\}$ converging to $0$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, proof-verification, induction

First, the question asks

> Prove that $1+\frac12+\frac13+\cdots+\frac1n<2\sqrt n$

At first glance, I see that this is a proof involving induction, and I arrived at an inequality as shown below where I complete my proof:

> $$\frac1{\sqrt{k+1}-\sqrt k}<2k+2$$

Then, the question asks further

> Let $S_n=\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{2n}+\frac1{3n}+\cdots+\frac1{n^2}$ for each $n\in\Bbb N$. Prove that $\{S_n\}$ converges to $0.$

The second part of the question is where I am stuck. I don't know how I can make use of the first part of the question to answer the latter part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The second part of the question is where I am stuck at. I don't know how I can make use of the first part of the question to answer the latter part.

**Hint**

Note that (use of the first part in blue):
$$S_n = \frac{1}{n}\left( \color{blue}{1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+...+\frac{1}{n}}\right) \color{blue}{\le} \frac{1}{n}\cdot \color{blue}{2\sqrt{n}} = \ldots$$

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}S_n&=\frac1n+\frac1{2n}+\frac1{3n}+\cdots+\frac1{n^2}\\[10pt]
&=\frac1n\left(1+\frac12+\frac13+\cdots+\frac1n\right)\\[10pt]
&\leqslant\frac{2\sqrt n}n\\[10pt]
&=\frac2{\sqrt n}.\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Using the first part of the question:
$$S_n=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{kn}=\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1n$$
$$<\frac1n\cdot2\sqrt n=\frac2{\sqrt n}$$
Since $S_n$ is bounded below by 0 and  bounded above by $\frac2{\sqrt n}$, whose limit as $n\to\infty$ is also 0, $S_n$ converges to 0.